# Bash Array does not store correctly

Tags: bash, array

I have a problem with my bash array I was trying to read the file however the array allocated it in array[1] instead of 0

```
#!/bin/bash
index=0
INPUT=BookDB.txt
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=:
i=0
book=()
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read bookname author price quantity sold
do
#echo "BookName : $bookname"
#echo "Author : $author"
#echo "Price : $price"
#echo "Quantity : $quantity"
#echo "Sold : $sold"

    book+=("$bookname")
    author+=("$author")
    price+=("$price")
    quant+=("$quantity")
    sold+=("$sold") 

 done < $INPUT
 IFS=$OLDIFS



 # Use c style for loop
 # get total subscripts in an array
 total=${#book[*]}
 # 
 for (( i=0; i<=$(( $total -1 )); i++ ))
  do
   echo $i "${book[$i]} "
 done

 total=${#author[*]}
 # 
 for (( i=0; i<=$(( $total -1 )); i++ ))
 do
  echo  $i "${author[$i]} "
 done
```

Here is the output of the file

Book

```
0 Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince 
1 The little Red Riding Hood 
2 Harry Potter - The Phoniex 
3 Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow 
4 Little Prince 
5 Lord of The Ring 
6 Three Little Pig 
7 All About Ubuntu 
8 Catch Me If You Can 
9 Happy Day
```

Author

```
0  
1 J.K Rowling 
2 Dan Lin 
3 J.K Rowling 
4 Dan Lin 
5 The Prince 
6 Johnny Dept 
7 Andrew Lim 
8 Ubuntu Team 
9 Mary Ann 
10 Mary Ann
```

Somehow the array for author[0] is empty

Comment: There's one namespace for scalar and array variables, and in `bash` and `ksh`, arrays just extend scalar variables. `$author` is `${author[0]}`, `author=x` or `read author` is assigning to `author[0]`. Use different variable names in your `read` statement.

Comment: BTW, you'd be better off using `perl` or `awk` for that rather than `bash` loops and arrays.

Answer (score 3):

`book` is initialized to the empty array by the line `book=()`, so during the first run through the loop `book+=("$bookname")` sets the first element of the array `book` (i.e. `${book[0]}`) to the first book name.

`author` is used sometimes as an array and sometimes as a scalar. In ksh and bash, when an array is referenced using a scalar syntax (i.e. anything other than `${VAR[INDEX]}`), the first element of the array is used. Assigning to the variable in a way other than `VAR=…`, such as via the `read` builtin, sets the first element of the array. Conversely, if an array is expected, a scalar variable is treated as a one-word array. Thus:

- On the first run through the loop, `author` contains the string `J.K Rowling`, then `author+=("$author")` sets it to a two-element array containing `J.K Rowling` twice.
- On the second run through the loop, `read` sets `${author[0]}` to `Dan Lin`, then `author+=("$author")` appends `Dan Lin`, yielding the three-element array `('Dan Lin' 'J.K. Rowling' 'Dan Lin')`.
- …
- On the last run, `read` sees an empty line, so it sets `$bookname`, `${author[0]}` and the others to an empty string.

To fix this, use a different name for the loop variables and for the arrays where you accumulate the data.

```
titles=()
authors=()
prices=()
quantities=()
sales=()
while read title author price quantity sold
do
    titles+=("$title")
    authors+=("$author")
    prices+=("$price")
    quantities+=("$quantity")
    sales+=("$sold") 
 done < $INPUT
```

Comment: If your `bash` is new enough, there's a `readarray` command.

Comment: @RickyBeam `readarray` doesn't break the line into fields, so I don't see how it's useful here.

Comment: Depends on the final purpose of his script.  I don't see where 5 arrays are necessary, but we don't know what the final produce is supposed to do.